# Ves Image Slider require.js issue in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, requirejs, slider

After installing Ves Image Slider on my magento 2.3 project, my backend WYSIWYG stops running on block edit page . and gives error of require.js like given below. When i disable the module, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Its giving 500 that means here is error just enable error from app/bootstrap.php uncomment that line ini_set('display_errors', 1); then check again.

Comment: try to redeploy static view files for adminhtml area

Answer (score 2):

Your installed Ves Extension is not compatible with magento 2.3, hence you should upgrade it to latest version. Magento older versions has tinymce 3 and its js file was defined as **tinymce** in `requirejs-config.js` file, but in Magento 2.3 have used latest tinymce version and defined with as **tinymce4** in `requirejs-config.js` file. so you have to change defined keyword in ves extension where is **tinymce**.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because **Ves Image slider use TinyMCE 3 but Magento2.3 use TinyMCE 4.**

You may **stop using any TinyMCE code for VES Slider** but you if you do that 
**WYSIWYG editor for Ves Slider under Widget will not work** (see attached image).

[image]

I know the solution I provided here is not the best solution but to make WYSIWYG editor workable for other Admin areas (like CMS Pages, Blocks, etc ) you may follow below steps.

step 1) open the file **default.xml** under ***MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Ves/ImageSlider/view/adminhtml/layout***

Update FIle **default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Venustheme
 * 
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 * 
 * This source file is subject to the Venustheme.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.venustheme.com/license-agreement.html
 * 
 * DISCLAIMER
 * 
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 * 
 * @category   Venustheme
 * @package    Ves_Productlist
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2014 Venustheme (http://www.venustheme.com/)
 * @license    http://www.venustheme.com/LICENSE-1.0.html
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Ves_ImageSlider::css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="js">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Ves_ImageSlider::wysiwyg/js.phtml" name="imageslider.wysiwyg.js"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Venustheme
 * 
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 * 
 * This source file is subject to the Venustheme.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.venustheme.com/license-agreement.html
 * 
 * DISCLAIMER
 * 
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 * 
 * @category   Venustheme
 * @package    Ves_Productlist
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2014 Venustheme (http://www.venustheme.com/)
 * @license    http://www.venustheme.com/LICENSE-1.0.html
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Ves_ImageSlider::css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="js">
            <!--<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Ves_ImageSlider::wysiwyg/js.phtml" name="imageslider.wysiwyg.js"/>-->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 2:** Rename the file **requirejs-config.js** to **requirejs-config.js__**   under
 ***MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Ves/ImageSlider/view/adminhtml/***

**Step 3:** Clear Magento Cache and remove static files.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to the issue to to change the default editor inside magento to tinymce3:

```
Config -> General -> Content Management
```

This will at least get the editor working for you.