# Edit action is missing in every back-end grid of magento 2.3.2

Tags: migration, magento2.3.2

I upgrade my Magento store from Magento 2.1.16 to Magento 2.3.2
Magento backend does not show any edit action see screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

I got knockout js error also in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return
>   $col.isSingle($row()._rowIndex) }" Message: Unable to process binding
>   "repeat: function(){return
>   {foreach:$col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex),item:'$action'} }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "attr: function(){return
>   {target:$col.getTarget($action()),href:$action().href} }" Message:
>   $col.getTarget is not a function
>       at attr (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:1), :3:77)
>       at update (knockout.js:353)
>       at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:314)
>       at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:208)
>       at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:204)
>       at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:202)
>       at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:193)
>       at knockout.js:314
>       at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:16)
>       at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:311)
>   [image]
>   what will be the cause of the issue?

Comment: tinymce.js is missing as its giving 404 error. try to fix that first.

Comment: have you any idea how to fix tinymce.js is missing as its giving 404 error

Comment: JS minify is enabled? Also, try a search for text 'tinymce' in your app magento directory to check any module is overriding it.

Comment: Merging is enable rest are disable

Comment: Also, try a search for text 'tinymce' in your app magento directory to check any module is overriding it.

Comment: https://nimb.ws/DZnMcA

Comment: serach result https://nimb.ws/1ve2jD

Comment: try php bin/magento mo:di Ves_ImageSlider  and check the spelling of the module

Comment: disabling module, The error has gone away but the slider is not working at my front end

Comment: edit actions are coming now?

Comment: no. Edit actions are still missing

Comment: have tried upgrade, compile and deploy

Comment: yes. I did all  upgrade, compile and deploy

Comment: try this last solution from here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272418/ves-image-slider-require-js-issue-in-magento-2-3

Comment: I tried the TinyMCE error gone. But edit actions are still missing

Comment: @AmritPalSingh thanks for the tip, it worked for me. can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it? May be due to some caching issue. It does not work yesterday.

Comment: So now using another slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the module which is overriding the 'tinymce'.

> php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_ModuleName

and check the namespace of the module. I hope it will fix the error.

If you want this module you can disable the TinyMCE from the XML of the module which is adding the js or can update the TinyMCE as Magento 2.3 uses TinyMCE 4.